# How to use two timers 1 and 4 simultaneously in Arduino Mega 2560

Tags: library

I activated timer 1 and its interrupt on the 2560 board and it works properly. Now I want to run Timer 4 as well. I installed the Timer 4 library, but when I compile the program, I get the following error. This error also occurs for timers 3 and 5:

```
C:\Users\win 8\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Timer5\Timer5.cpp:110:6: 
note: 'void startSlowCountingTimer5()' previously defined here
 void startSlowCountingTimer5(void) {
```

Thank you for your help.

The full text of the error is as follows

```
C:\Users\win 8\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Timer5\Timer5.cpp: In function 'void startSlowCountingTimer5()':

C:\Users\win 8\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Timer5\Timer5.cpp:127:6: error: redefinition of 'void startSlowCountingTimer5()'

 void startSlowCountingTimer5(void) {

C:\Users\win 8\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Timer5\Timer5.cpp:110:6: note: 'void startSlowCountingTimer5()' previously defined here

 void startSlowCountingTimer5(void) {
```

Comment: is it actually an error?

Comment: If you want to use Timer4, why did you include the Timer5 library? Please show your code and the whole error message

Comment: And also provide a link to every library that you are using

Comment: This error also occurs for each of the three timers 3, 4 and 5

Comment: I downloaded Timer 1 from the Arduino site, which worked fine.

Comment: But I downloaded the library of timers 3, 4 and 5 from this site https://github.com/carlosrafaelgn/ArduinoTimer

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in the library that [was fixed in 2017](https://github.com/carlosrafaelgn/ArduinoTimer/pull/2)! Please
upgrade.

Comment: Thank you "Edgar" for your guidance. My problem is solved.